# is it possible to convert a radio field to look like a checkbox?

Tags: javascript, css

i was wondering if eitehr through css or javascript that if its possible to make a radio field look like a square instead of the circle?

it was a request from a customer, kinda weird but they want it.

Comment: This is one of those exceptions to the "customer is always right" rule.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible, but you can change a check box's behaviour using JavaScript.

Don't do it, though. Really don't. Messing with the basics of the user interface is almost *always* a foolish thing.

Check the [interface hall of shame](http://homepage.mac.com/bradster/iarchitect/shame.htm) for examples of mis-used controls and very good explanations about what's wrong with them. [Using checkboxes for radio buttons](http://homepage.mac.com/bradster/iarchitect/controls.htm) is there, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can place a checkbox on the form that will control the `checked` property of an invisible radio button. I would encourage your client to seek other options though.

Perhaps they actually want a checkbox?